# Convert 16 (0xEFF) to NSString

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, int

Hey I have stuck on how to convert my int value to NSString and get correct value

I have unsigned int

```
 unsigned int r = 0xEFF;
```

and I like to have NSString like @"EFF", not @"3839"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same format strings as printf:

```
NSString* newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%x", r];
```

Comment: Thanks you for a quick answer! awesome!